# invert text color based on background in css

Tags: css, text, colors, background, less

I have a grid of different shades of blue, they each contain text, I need the text to be white if the background is dark and vice versa, I have:

```
color: #333;
isolation: isolate;
mix-blend-mode: difference;
```

but that somehow changes the background colour of the elements to some wierd orangy grey. Is there a CSS-only (less-only) option that will invert the text colour only?

Comment: I hope you would find this useful https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/

Comment: I have that excact tab open and the MDN page for it, but that somehow changes the background colour to some orange colour.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could also apply this styling to the element you'd like to invert the colors of:

```
filter: invert(1);
mix-blend-mode: difference;
```

It especially works if you need to base the difference on a **child** or a element **further away**, not a parent or a close element.

I used it with a custom cursor (the black circle), which made it contrast nicely with the elements behind. Sample pen here: https://codepen.io/m3t4lch7/pen/VwwOKNd

[image: Cursor with inverted colors]

Answer (score 8):

You can set the text color to `transparent`, and use `background-clip` and `filter` to invert and grayscale the color displayed through the transparent text.

Check out a more detailed explanation of the various effects you can achieve this way at [Methods for Contrasting Text Against Backgrounds](https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/).

In your case, it sounds like you are looking for something like the following:

```css
#one {
  background-color: blue;
}

#two {
  background-color: white;
}

span {
  background: inherit;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  filter: invert(1) grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: invert(1) grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however this is not quite the result I was looking for, I. the effect makes the actual text invisible, I would like the text to have the inverse colour.

Comment: Probably a browser specific issue. Edited the answer for improved browser support after testing on Chrome and Firefox (also removed contrast from filter as it seems to have little effect in some browsers, but know that experimenting with the filter values including chaining additional filters may enable a better rendering of the text color, contrast, etc).

Comment: I use Chrome Canary. I also tried it in IE and Edge. But thank you.

Comment: Tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge and it works for me. Maybe there is some conflicting css on the site you are testing.

Comment: there probably is, if it worked for you, then I don't see why it shouldn't work. thanks for trying.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with gray background-color: #808080.

Comment: @blow - that is true. Inverting a color basically subtracts the color from `rgb(255, 255, 255)`, so a gray color like the one you note in your comment would be `rgb(128, 128, 128)` which would invert to `rgb(127, 127, 127)` so the inverted text would blend right in with the background color.

Comment: @blow - to be clear on the previous comment, fully inverting a color using `invert(1)` results in the simple formula above (using a different inversion value makes the math slightly more complicated).